# Failing to use FreeAdhocUDF with Firebird 3/4 on Debian 11

Tags: firebird

We have problems to use the FreeAdhocUDF library http://freeadhocudf.org with Firebird on Debian 11.

Some basic info:

- Debian 11 64bit
- `uname -a` says:

  ```
  Linux RMVM18 5.10.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21)
  x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

Firebird was installed via `apt`, with these packages:

```
firebird3.0-common 3.0.7.33374.ds
firebird3.0-server 3.0.7.33374.ds
firebird3.0-server-core q3.0.7.33374.ds
firebird3.0-utils q3.0.7.33374.ds
```

and later directly using the installation packages from https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0/#Linux_AMD64.

Finally, we tried the version 4 of Firebird, but with no luck either: https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/releases/download/v4.0.2/Firebird-4.0.2.2816-0.amd64.tar.gz

Firebird itself runs perfect in both versions. Only the usage of the FreeAdhocUDF fails.

We checked the dependencies of the lib with

```bash
ldd FreeAdhocUDF.so
```

successfully, result was:

```
cd.1 (0x00007fff557da000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fae5a559000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fae5a384000)
libib_util.so => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libib_util.so (0x00007fae5a37f000)
libicudataFAU.so.44 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudataFAU.so.44
(0x00007fae5933f000)
libicui18nFAU.so.44 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18nFAU.so.44
(0x00007fae58f65000)
libicuucFAU.so.44 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuucFAU.so.44
(0x00007fae58c12000)
libfbclient.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2
(0x00007fae58a6e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fae5a8d3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(0x00007fae58a4c000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fae58a46000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fae58879000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fae5885f000)
libtommath.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtommath.so.1
(0x00007fae5883d000)
```

Settings in `firebird.conf`:

`UdfAccess = Restrict` (we tried several options including `Full`)

No matter which of the variants described below we tried, the result was always this:

```sql
Select f_abs(-1) from rdb$database;
```

```
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes
successful execution of subsequent statements.
Use of UDF/BLOB-filter module at location FreeAdhocUDF is not
allowed by server configuration.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLCODE: -902
SQLSTATE: 28000
GDSCODE: 335544831
```

What is wrong? What else can we try?

Comment: Is the setting value literally `Restrict`? Because in that case you haven't specified the allowed locations for UDF libraries, so Firebird will load none.

Comment: As an aside, why use a UDF for `F_ABS` which I assume gets the absolute value, when Firebird has it built-in as [`ABS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-abs)?

Comment: Sorry, we used not only `Restrict`, but in combination with several paths, relative, absolute, and in the end we tried `Full` to be sure not to pitfall there.

Comment: What is the definition of `F_ABS`, because then it suggests the definition is incorrect (as in, it can't find the right library).

Comment: If it were only F_ABS, I would agree, but we have to use a BIG amount of code which heavily uses several FreeAdhoc functions :-(

Comment: OK, but if this gives an error, even when you have `UdfAccess = Full`, then that it could mean that the definition is incorrect, and the library could not be loaded (though to be honest, then I would expect the error _"module name or entrypoint could not be found"_ instead of the error you show in your question). So having an example of the definition of one of the UDFs that failed could be helpful.

Comment: Newbie question: I tried to indicate that in the meantime we found the solution, and I myself really appreciate threads with a hint that in the end of the thread there is a solution. So I edited the title adding "SOLVED", but somebody deleted that. Why? I am sure there are reasons for this, but how can I achieve to signal "we found the solution"? I want to learn an make it correctly, I tried to contact the editing user but found no way either, so I am trying to find out here...

Comment: You mark a question as solved by accepting an answer (clicking the checkmark in front of that answer). If none of the current answers provide the solution, post your own answer with the solution and accept that after the timeout (you cannot immediately accept your own answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was: We worked with symbolic links all over the place (the usual strategy), but finally we had to **copy** `FreeAdhocUDF_FB2x_amd64.so` explicitly to `FreeAdhocUDF.so`. That solved the problem.

Further info: We used the directory `/UDF/` as the location for the UDF and had `UdfAccess = Restrict /UDF` in the `firebird.config` (Firebird 4.)

Comment: Yes, links don't work with restricted UDF locations because technically the library is out of allowed directory which is compared literally.

Comment: The location was identical. Both - the original file and the symbolic link - where in `/UDF`. The COPY was allowed to bind, the symbolic link not. 
In the case of the several special library files like `libicuucFAU.so.44` it was okay to symlink. In fact the installation script itsself worked like that. So it was not clear at all to us that in THIS case it had to be a copy. We found out by incident, it was kind of a last guess.

Answer (score 1):

Error text is: "Use of UDF/BLOB-filter module at location FreeAdhocUDF **is not allowed by server configuration**". Failed dependency or missed library would give you "module name or entrypoint could not be found" error.

Value "Restict" must be followed by list of directories where UDF libraries are allowed (and actually looked for). Simple "Restrict" is meaningless and most likely allow UDF libraries to reside only in Firebird root directory which is a bad idea.

If you set UdfAccess to "full" you have to provide an absolute path to the library in "DECLARE FUNCTION" query.

Remember that Firebird server (if configured as SuperServer or SuperClassic) must be restarted to reflect changes in configuration.

For detailed investigation you can use dltrace utility to see where the library is tried to be loaded from.

Comment: I agree - the problem does NOT seem to be failing inclusions. "not allowed"... but where is the config preventing the server from using the UDF?

Sorry, I described not very well... we didn't use `Restrict` alone, but using several options, direct paths, relative, and in the end we tried `Full` to not pitfall there.

Thanks for the hint regarding the DECLARE paths! We'll try that!

Comment: @Uwe I bet that you forgot to restart Firebird server after changing firebird.conf.

Comment: we restarted every time after changing .conf or file structure/names/rights by sysctl restart